# Reverse theorem defined independently of how a theorem is expressed

Tags: logic

The reverse theorem for a theorem $A\Rightarrow B$ is by definition $B\Rightarrow A$.

But what if a theorem is expressed with other logical symbols? For example $A\Rightarrow B$ can be rewritten as $0\lor(\lnot A\lor B)$.

Is reverse theorem well defined independently of how a theorem is expressed?

Comment: I have never heard the term "reverse" theorem.  The *converse" of $A\implies B$ is $B\implies A$ and the term "converse" only applies to formulas of the form something implies something else.

Answer (score 0):

It is not well defined becuase $A\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $1\Rightarrow(A\Rightarrow B)$ but $B\Rightarrow A$ is not equivalent to $(A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow 1$ that is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark wrote in the coment, I also think that it's called "converse" instead of "reverse".

Besides, your answer is not completely correct, because the fact that $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow 1$ is not equivalent to $(B\rightarrow A)$ is because the first is always true, but not the second one $\left(\right.$I don't know what you tried to say about $\lnot(A\rightarrow B)\left.\right)$.

Moreover, when you write an equivalent expression for $A\rightarrow B$ that makes appear news conditionals ($\rightarrow$), notice that when you convert them, you are not converting exactly the same $\rightarrow$. Look it at the example of your answer!

Comment: Sorry, stupid error by me, corrected.